# Cannot connect to query from python using Service account with BigQuery Job User role (in IAM)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Cloud team granted to me a Service account (SA) with BigQuery Job User role (IAM) for query from python.
But i got that issue

> 403 request failed: the user does not have
> 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission to project

But this SA is worked in Java. Looking for ideas to solve this, thanks ^^

My simple code here:

```
import pandas as pd
import google.cloud.bigquery as gbq
gbq_client = gbq.Client.from_service_account_json('credentials/credentials_bigquery.json')

#function query
def query_job(client,query):
    query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.
    df_from_bq = query_job.to_dataframe()
    return df_from_bq

#query 
qr_user = """
            SELECT user_id FROM `CUSTOMER_DATA_PLATFORM.CDP_TBL` LIMIT 1000
          """
user = query_job(gbq_client,qr_user)
```

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?